# Two way clustering in ordered logit model, restricting rstudent to mitigate outlier effects

Tags: stata

I have an ordered dependent variable (1 through 21) and continuous independent variables. I need to run the ordered logit model, clustering by firm and time, eliminating outliers with Studentized Residuals <-2.5 or > 2.5. I just know `ologit` command and some options for the command; however, I have no idea about how to do two way clustering and eliminate outliers with studentized residuals:

```
ologit rating3 securitized retained, cluster(firm)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, two way clustering has only been extended to a few estimation commands (like ivreg2 from scc and tobit/logit/probit [here](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/petersen/htm/papers/se/se_programming.htm)). Eliminating outliers can easily be done on your own and there's no automated way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the logit2.ado from the link Dimitriy gave (Mitchell Petersen's website) and modify it to use the ologit command.  It's simple enough to do with a little trial and error.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable with 21 ordinal categories, I would have no problems treating that as a continuous one. If you want to back that up somehow, I wrote a paper on welfare measurement with ordinal variables, see [DOI:10.1111/j.1475-4991.2008.00309.x](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1475-4991.2008.00309.x). Then you can use `ivreg2`. You should be aware of all the issues involved with that estimator, in particular, that it implicitly assumed that the correlations are fully modeled by this two-way structure, and observations for firms `i` and `j` and times `t` and `s` are definitely uncorrelated for `i!=j` and `t!=s`. Sometimes, this is a strong assumption to make -- i.e., New York and New Jersey may be correlated in 2010, but New York 2010 is uncorrelated with New Jersey 2009.

I have no idea of what you might mean by ordinal outliers. Somebody must have piled a bunch of dissertation advice (or worse analysis requests) without really trying to make sense of every bit.